# Hardcoding value into Coredata using RestKit for iOS

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using the latest RestKit for iOS.  I have a few different APIs that I want to map into the same CoreData Object.  I am trying to hard code a value in field on the object that identifies which API the data came from.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the RKEntityMapping for RestKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your API field, which will store this value, to `transient` in your core data object. Next add block with [setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKResponseMapperOperation.html#//api/name/setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock%3a) in which you add an appropriative indicator value to the mapping dictionary.